# Stored procedure execution taking long time while retrieving more than 2 set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on SQL server 2008. I am new to stored procedure. I wrote one stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IBSFCDINP] @Carid NVARCHAR(50)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
  SELECT

     k.HBarcode, m.make,t.Compl,
    t.plateno,t.self,t.dtime, v.vtype, l.locname,case when l.edt is null or l.edt =0 then l.minEdt +l.BuffrEDT else l.edt + l.BuffrEDT end as EDT,  t.locid,t.vtid,t.lsttic,
     c.Colname, te.UniqueName,DATEDIFF(minute,t.dtime,getdate()) as Duration,pl.PS,pc.PlateCode

  FROM dbo.Transaction_tbl t

  left JOIN KHanger_tbl k ON t.transactID = k.transactID
  left JOIN make_tbl m ON t.mkid = m.mkid 
left join PlateSource_tbl pl on t.PSID=pl.PSID
left join PlateCode_tbl pc on t.PCdID=pc.PCdID
  left JOIN vtype_tbl v ON v.vtid = t.vtid 
  left  JOIN Location_tbl l ON t.locid = l.locid 

  left JOIN Color_tbl C ON t.colid = c.colid 
  left JOIN Terminals_tbl te ON k.tid = te.tid

 WHERE t.tbarcode = @carid 
if(select COUNT(t1.Compl) from dbo.Transaction_tbl t1 where T1.TBarcode=@Carid)=1
begin
declare @compl integer =null,
@transid integer=null,
@complid integer=null
select @transid=t.transactID from dbo.Transaction_tbl t where t.TBarcode=@carid
Select @compl=co.Cmplid from dbo.ComplimentTransactAssign_tbl co where co.TransactID=@transid
select c.CompName,c1.Remarks from Complimentary_tbl c 
 inner join ComplimentTransactAssign_tbl c1 on c.CmplID=c1.Cmplid where c.CmplID=@compl and c1.TransactID=@transid
end
declare @locatnid integer,
@location nvarchar(100)
begin
select @locatnid= t.Locid from dbo.Transaction_tbl t where t.TBarcode=@carid
select l1.StartTime,l1.EndTime from dbo.Location_tbl l1 where l1.Locid=@locatnid
end
END
```

my database have more than 600K records. Stored procedure it taking long time to execute. I want to optimize it as much as possible.  is there any way to write this stored procedure simpler than this way
Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a lot to optimize on the SP as much as whoever wrote the database needs to learn SQL and know what an index is.

The SQL Looks quite ok to me - but without indices even tiny databases such as yours (yes, 600.000 rows is nothing - it was small 25 years ago at Foxpro times, it is nothing today) will take ages to make joins.

THere are minor parts you can optimize, but I would start running it in management studio asking for the assumed AND executed query plans and fixnig likely the fadct that there are no indices on any of the tables that are needed.

Comment: sir then why it s taking long time to execute?

Comment: am taking 3 separate row of out put..that s why??

Comment: @user3252014 Did they teach you to read? My answer clearly tells you how to approach the issue. "Missing idices". What part of that do you refuse to understand? http://http://use-the-index-luke.com/